# Output either 0 or 1 for every 24 frames using animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I want an output of 0 for the first 24 frames, 1 for the next 24 frames, 0 again for the next 24 frames and so on. 
That is, at frame one the output text is 0 and after 24 frames the output changes to 1 and after the next 24 frames the output changes to 0 again.
How do I do this using animation nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example,

1) Repeat node is giving values from 0 to 47 i.e 48 when the rate is 48.

2) Because repeat node also count **0**, so I have substracted **1** from frame.

3) Then using compare boolean and switch nodes we can choose **0** for **0-23** frames (24) and for next **24-47** (24) frames, **1**.

4) Last I use float text node to convert float to text and text object output to text-object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after some thinking I found the right nodes and it wasn't as complicated as I thought it to be. I've attached a picture of the node tree.
[image]